# Dúvida sobre armazenamento do resultado da função em uma lista e os tipos de variáveis armazenados

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Post Inicial

estou fazendo um código simples que me da a variação % entre dois números, A e B. ASsim que ele calcula essa variação %, ele deveria anexar o resultado da operação em uma lista que a princípio está vazia.

**Porém eu obtenho o resultado None, poderiam me dizer porque está sendo preenchido com None e não com o valor float gerado pela função ?**

Além disso, quando eu aperto type(VariacaoPercentual(a,b)) ele não me retorna um float.

```
a = float(input("Insira o valor inicial")
b = float(input("Insira o valor final")
c = []
def VariacaoPercentual(a,b):
print(((a/b)-1)*100)
c.append(VariacaoPercentual(a,b))
print(c)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edit 1 : ---------------------

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque não consigo fazer `c.append(j)`, sendo que j é o próprio valor que a função retorna?

Edit 2 --- Resposta nos comentários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja calcular a variação percentual, primeiramente você deve conhecer a lógica do cálculo.

A fórmula para se calcular a variação percentual é:

```
variação percentual = ((vf / vi) - 1) * 100
```

1. **vf** é o valor atual;
2. **vi** é o valor antigo.

Outra coisa, no cálculo da variação percentual poderá haver valores com sinal positivo - identificando uma taxa de aumento - e valores com sinal negativo - especificando uma taxa de queda. Além disso, se **vf = vi** não haverá variação percentual.

Pois bem, uma das forma para se calcular a variação percentual é:

```
def variacao_percentual(vi, vf):
    return ((vf / vi) - 1) * 100


v_inicial = float(input('Insira o valor inicial: '))
v_final = float(input('Insira o valor final: '))

percentual = variacao_percentual(v_inicial, v_final)

if percentual < 0:
    print(f'Taxa de queda foi: {percentual:.1f} %')
elif percentual == 0:
    print(f'Não existi variação percentual!')
else:
    print(f'Taxa de aumento foi: {percentual:.1f} %')
```

Observe que quando executamos o código devemos inserir o valor inicial e final e, depois pressionar enter. Posteriormente, os valores serão passados para a função `variacao_percentual(vi, vf)` e, consequentemente, o valore será calculado sendo, em seguida, exibido o resultado.

**Testando o código**

**Taxa de queda:**

Imagine que queremos descobrir a **variação percentual** de um produto que na semana passada custava R$ 100,00 e hoje está custando R$ 80,00. Neste caso, executamos o código e quando recebermos a mensagem `Insira o valor inicial:` , devemos digitar **100** seguidamente de um `enter` e, quando recebermos a mensagem `insira o valor final:` , devemos digitar **80** e pressionar enter.

Neste momento o cálculo será realizado e receberemos como saída:

```
Taxa de queda foi: -20.0 %
```

**Taxa de aumento:**

Imagine que queremos descobrir a **variação percentual** de um produto que na semana passada custava R$ 100,00 e hoje está custando R$ 120,00. Neste caso, executamos o código e quando recebermos a mensagem `Insira o valor inicial:` , devemos digitar **100** seguidamente de um `enter` e, quando recebermos a mensagem `insira o valor final:` , devemos digitar **120** e pressionar enter.

Neste momento o cálculo será realizado e receberemos como saída:

```
Taxa de aumento foi: 20.0 %
```

Answer (score 1):

A função não esta retornando nada, nao tem retorno, coloca o return

```
 def VariacaoPercentual(a,b):
   print(((a/b)-1)*100)
   return ((a/b)-1)*100
```

Comment: Olá camarada, editei o post com a dúvida. 

Consegui fazer o que você sugeriu e passou a retornar o valor certo, porém não entendi porque não posso usar c.append(j) ao invés de c.append(Função(a,b))

Comment: j é uma variavel local só exite dentro da funcao VariacaoPercentual(a,b)

Comment: E além do que disse @Bernardo Lopes, vc pode adicionar qualquer coisa dentro de uma lista menos funções, classes e essas coisas...

Comment: @BernardoLopes, então o resultado da função só existe dentro. Um escopo local, entendi. 

É possível eu pegar o resultado da função e armazenar num escopo global ?
Futuramente, pretendo aproveitar esse mesmo código para criar uma função que calcula variações % sucessivas.

Comment: @CarlosCortez, Porém posso associar o resultado numérico gerado por uma função e preencher a lista apenas com os resultados ? Acho que essa era minha dúvida, mas não soube expressá-la corretamente.

Comment: Sim, declara j fora da funcao perto do a, b, c que sao variaveis globais

Answer (score 1):

```
a = float(input("Insira o valor inicial")
b = float(input("Insira o valor final")
c = []
def variacao_percentual(a,b):
    print(((a/b)-1)*100)
    c.append(((a/b)-1)*100)
    print(c)
variacao_percentual(a,b)
```

Edit 1 :
pra conseguir guardar os valor na lista, é possível fazer o seguinte:

```
c = []
def variacao_percentual():
    a = float(input("Insira o valor inicial"))
    b = float(input("Insira o valor final"))
    print(((a/b)-1)*100)
    c.append(((a/b)-1)*100)
    print(c)
```

e chamar a função sempre que precisar inserir novo dado na lista

```
variacao_percentual()
```

lembrando que essa lista não é um banco de dados e os dados são temporários.

Comment: Oi camarada, pelo método que você descreveu, ele exibe a lista C com apenas um resultado. Logo, quando eu fizer novamente o processo, a lista passará a ter o tamanho 1 novamente porém com outro valor. Foi o que aconteceu na minha IDLE

Comment: Então não é um programa simples, como descrito na pergunta =P

Comment: Vc precisa ver os resultados sempre que insere?... poderia fazer um loop com algum critério de parada

Comment: Sim, diga-se de passagem. Consegui armazenar a lista com mais valores, o problema era que eu não estava separando as linhas de código de maneira apropriada no VSCode e a lista reiniciava a cada vez que eu compilava o código.

Comment: Obrigado por esse método. Vou adaptar o código ao seu método e fazer um edit com a sua contribuição e a do Solkarped.

Eu não achei que o problema não seria simples, esse código surgiu enquanto eu tentava estudar um livro de matemática.